# Function output is twice as large as it should be, however is halved if I print function to the console first with no other changes

Tags: c#

I am trying to approximate pi using Buffon's Needle method, where by finding the probability of a dropped needle crossing a line you can get pi. I have a function called getHitNum() that simulates randomly throwing a needle and checks if the needle has crossed a line. The formula for Buffon's needle is pi=(total drops * 2)/(drops where needle crosses line). I do the math for this formula in a variable called piEstimate. Currently my program gives me twice the amount pi should be, or approximately 6.2. However if I print getHitNum() before plugging it into piEstimate (where the comment "Console.WriteLine(getHitNum())" is ), then I approximately get pi. I am confused by this, it's almost as if the program doubles getHitNum() incorrectly unless I print it first. How can printing my function halve the result as opposed to if I didn't print it. I am new to programming so sorry if any incorrect terminology made this confusing to understand. Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks :).

```
double dropNum;
double piEstimate;
int hitNum = 0;
string userInput = "yes";


Random rnd = new Random();

while (userInput == "yes")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input desired number of simulations (between 10,000 and 1,000,000 are recommended)");
    dropNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine().Replace(",", ""));

    //Console.WriteLine(getHitNum());
    piEstimate = dropNum * 2 / getHitNum();
    Console.WriteLine("Pi is approximately " + piEstimate);
    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to run program again");
    userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    userInput.ToLower();
    hitNum = 0;
}

int getHitNum()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= dropNum; i++)
    {
        double randAngle = rnd.NextDouble() * 360;
        double randDistance = rnd.NextDouble() - .5;

        double height = Math.Sin(randAngle) * .5;
        double maxHeight = randDistance + height;
        double minHeight = randDistance - height;

        if (minHeight < 0 && maxHeight > 0)
        {
            hitNum++;
        }
    }
    return hitNum;
}
```

Comment: If you end up calling `getHitNum` twice you end up modifying your static (and thus shared) variables twice. This is the reason why your output differ. I don't know how to fix your algorithm though, but I thought I'd at least tell you why you're getting different answers. To avoid different answers, make all variables that `getHitNum` requires local so that one call/execution doesn't impact another.

Comment: The pitfall of global state. Don't use shared or static variables is you don't need to, just as Lasse says. But also *please* clean up your question. It's a waterfall of text right now. Very hard to read and comprehend.